# Merging trigger handlers to handle bulk records?

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I have two triggers in Opportunity and these triggers are handler from two different handler classes, now I want them as one class.

1.

```
if(trigger.isAfter){
        if(trigger.isUpdate){
            try{
                Oppclass.afterInsertOpportunity(trigger.new, null);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                system.debug('OpportunityTrigger=>isAfter=>isInsert=>'+ex.getMessage() +'-----Line Number--->'+ex.getLineNumber());
                oppClass.secondMethod(false,false,false,false);
            }
        }
```

2.

```
    List<Opportunity> optyList = new List<Opportunity>();
      for(Opportunity o:Trigger.new){
        if(trigger.isupdate && trigger.isAfter){
            //some condition
              optyList.add(o);

opportunityclass.method(list of opp);
```

Now i want to merge these two triggers in one trigger that it will work fine and handle all the bulk records.

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do here is add the method class to the first trigger.

```
    if(trigger.isAfter){
            if(trigger.isUpdate){
                try{
                    Oppclass.afterInsertOpportunity(trigger.new, null);
                    *opportunityclass.method(Trigger.new);*
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    system.debug('OpportunityTrigger=>isAfter=>isInsert=>'+ex.getMessage() +'-----Line Number--->'+ex.getLineNumber());
                    oppClass.secondMethod(false,false,false,false);
                }
            }
     }
```

Option 1 is the more desired way to put a trigger together.  Within your custom code, you always want to have 1 trigger per object.  Then, within your trigger, you can customize what happens with the data.  Specifically when it comes to order of operation of your code.  With 2 triggers, you do not know which will fire first.

There are a few variations on how to setup your trigger, but they are similar to this:

```
trigger standardOpportunity on Opportunity (after delete, after insert, after undelete, 
after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {
    // before stuff here
    if( trigger.isBefore )
    {
        if(trigger.isInsert)
        {
             // call class to do stuff
        }

        if(trigger.isUpdate)
        {            
            // call class to do stuff
        }

        if(trigger.isDelete)
        {
            // call class to do stuff
        }
    }
    // after stuff here
    if(trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if(trigger.isInsert)
        {   
            // call class to do stuff
        }
        if(trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            // call class to do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Now, keep in mind, this is a variation.  You want to keep it down to the necessary stuff you need to perform on each action.

What 'triggers' a trigger is some kind of DML on a record or set of records.  Hence the conditional check isAfter, isBefore etc prior to doing logic.  ALL of the records within the set are triggered off that DML.  So there is no need to loop through the triggers in isBefore isUpdate to add them to a list to do processing.  It will either always be that condition, or it will not be.

Triggers are also automatically bulkified.  This means that 200 records will be process in a trigger at a time.  So if 400 records are being updated at once, the trigger will run twice with 200 record increments.

When the desired conditions are met, send the entire list you want to process to your class.  I do not put logic in my triggers.  Business logic should be done in your classes that the trigger calls.  I would bet that some refactoring will need to be done to your OpportunityClass and OppClass to work together.

Finally, you should think about triggers in terms of the execution context.  What is the desired goal you want to happen when an opportunity is updated. Instead of adding an individual piece that doesn't fit well in the puzzle, you need to figure out the piece and how it fits into what is currently happening to the records at the given condition.

Please take a look at some apex coding best practices.  [This one](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) touches on the example I described and continues to take it much further in depth of what is possible with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you consider using a framework. We have adopted the [sfdc-trigger-framework](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework) so that we can use one handler class per object. You dont have to use this one as there are more if you just Google Apex Trigger Frameworks.